# Dipole Moment of a Homogenously charged cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, integration, dipole

A Homogenously charged cylinder of length L with Radius R and charged Q is presented. I am asked to find the dipole moment, the charge density is not given and only this Q value is given. I know the value must be zero due to the symmetry of the problem and that p the dipole moment is a vector quantity as such then you have p_x,y,z.
But the integration will not and cannot be zero due to the cylindrical co-ordinate being L for p_z

Can someone pleae explain how to find the dipole moment of the cylinder with a homogenous charge Q.

Comment: Fun fact:  if the net charge of an object is not zero, then the dipole moment depends on the choice of origin point.  So:  what origin point are you asked to find the dipole moment with respect to?